# Simulate real mouse click in Python or Node on Windows?

Tags: python, node.js, mouse

Currently I'm developing a auto-clicker for an application, but somehow it's blocking the clicks that's coming from scripts.

Currently I'm trying to achieve a simple click on the screen, such as:

```
import { mouseClick, moveMouse } from 'robotjs';

moveMouse(372, 404);
mouseClick('left');
```

Or in Python that I tried as well:

```
import pyautogui

pyautogui.click(372, 404)
```

Currently I tried those libs, but no luck at all, the window of the application is not even getting focused.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, basically you must run the application as admin if the program that you wanna click is runned as admin, complete missed that.